# using default constructor in constructor inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a template class "Derived" which does a constructor inheritance:

```
template <class T>
class Derived : public T
{
    using T::T;
    Derived()
    {
         std::cout<<"in derived"; 
    }
};
```

My base class has a constructor that expects arguments:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(int a)
    {
        std::cout<<"in base";
    }
};
```

When I create an object of type Derived it seems the derived constructor is not called:

```
Derived<Base> derived(2);
```

prints "in base";

Why? Is there a way to tell it to call Derived constructor?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be called? It's a parameterless constructor and you're calling a constructor with a parameter. Also, how is the template part relevant to the question? Wouldn't the same be true had it not been a template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialization by an inherited constructor happens as follows:

> **[class.inhctor.init]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.inhctor.init#1) When a constructor for type B is invoked to initialize an object of a different type D (that is, when the constructor was inherited), **initialization proceeds as if a defaulted default constructor were used to initialize the D object and each base class subobject from which the constructor was inherited, except that the B subobject is initialized by the invocation of the inherited constructor**. The complete initialization is considered to be a single function call; in particular, the initialization of the inherited constructor's parameters is sequenced before the initialization of any part of the D object.

The key point is the *defaulted* word. Defaulted c'tors are generated by the compiler, for instance a copy c'tor can be defaulted. And so it doesn't use any c'tor that's defined in the derived class. A compiler generated c'tor is always going to have an empty compound statement. So one should not expect anything to be printed.